# Python: document property to specify type

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, python-typing, docstring, numpydoc

Let's consider the following example:

```
from typing import Union
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None
        
    @property
    def x(self) -> Union[float, np.ndarray]:
        if len(self._x) == 1:
            return self._x[0]
        else:
            return self._x
    
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value: Union[float, list, np.ndarray]):
        self._x = np.atleast_1d(value)
```

Any suggestion on how can I properly document the above code?
I am using `Sphinx` and `numpydoc`.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** I realized that my question is not really clear so I'm going to add few words.
Basically, the main issue is how to document the fact that the `x` is a `float, list or array` in input and `float or array` as output. I saw in some examples that this should be done in the `getter` only and I don't know if I should add the keywords `Parameters` and `Returns` or if it is a better way to do it as I didn't find enough answers on this (or I just miss them).

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is the problem?

Comment: This extension might be of interest: https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autodoc-typehints/. Not sure if it works well with numpydoc though.

Answer (score 0):

You can just explicitly assign the `__doc__` attribute on the final property, like in:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None
        
    @property
    def x(self) -> Union[float, np.ndarray]:
        ...
    
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value: Union[float, list, np.ndarray]):
        ...

    x.__doc__ = """\
                 Documentation text goes here.
                 (you may want to call textwrap.dedent on this string)

                """
```